# Auto Highlight Active Row and Column

Tags: excel, vba

I managed to auto highlight active row and column by simply using copy paste to "view code".

But is there some simple way to make so that colors in other rows and columns cells remain the same as I have used before. Meaning only active area is changing and others are as original. Then worksheet would be more visual, not only boring white/black.

Answer (score 1):

simple method to highlight row. paste in sheet code

```
Dim OldColorIndex As Integer
Dim WorkRange As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not WorkRange Is Nothing Then WorkRange.Interior.ColorIndex = OldColorIndex
OldColorIndex = Target.Interior.ColorIndex
Set WorkRange = Nothing
Set WorkRange = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(Target.Row, 1), Cells(Target.Row, Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))
WorkRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
End Sub
```

Comment: Working, voted up. But it would be good to prevent the error appearing in case of multiple selection. In order to have a previous `OldColorIndex` I would recommend to transform the second code line in `OldColorIndex = IIf(Target.Rows.Count > 1, Target.Cells(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex, Target.Interior.ColorIndex)`...

Comment: i learn something new, never used that function. thanks

Comment: Thanks! But does not work for row + columns (cross) and original colors disappear when once clicked row where is some colored cells.

Comment: I need this action but the way original colors do not disappear: https://www.excelhow.net/auto-highlight-active-row-and-column.html

Comment: there is no simple way to do that. You can have many colors in one column. programically you can make array to remember all interior colors in each used range in selected column but it will cost a lot of computer memory and program will work slowly.

Comment: but You can easly edit that code from excelhow to highlight  font colour instead interior colour. just change interior.color to font.color. You can also bold and unbold font

Comment: Still all the colors in cells disappear.